# How to create Bottom bar with circle in the middle on iOS

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I was wondering how to create bottom bar like this in the enclosed photo. With something like circle in the middle.

[image: image with bottom bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `UITabBarController`. When you set it up into your app, it's default style is like the one in the app store. You can customize it afterward.